# Not sure why cron jobs are testing for ABSPATH and exiting

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cron-task, custom-wordpress-pages

Does anybody have experience running automated `cron` Jobs with

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
```

The automated `cron` Jobs I've setup aren't able to run because they're accessing the files directly. I need to make an exception for my server, I'm thinking maybe we could use something in the server's header file to make allow it through?

Looked all over Google and can't find anything, but surely people are running automated `cron` Jobs with the absolute path check in place? All ideas are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What are your cronjobs doing?   Either initialize the wordpress config or utilize the built in WP Cron.

Comment: If a script has that code at the top of the page then it clearly is not intended to be run without Wordpress loaded and called directly. Maybe show the full contents of the file (as long as they don't contain sensitive data) and describe what you want the cron job to do.

Comment: They do contain sensitive data unfortunately. The cron is running a php file on the site that updates a db.